# Jersey2.12 user guide on JAX-RS annotations on EJB interfaces for JAX-RS / EJB integration

Tags: ejb, jax-rs, integration, jersey-2.0

[JAX-RS/EJB integration : Jersey 2.12](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.javaee.ejb)

I was going through the guide in the link above and came across the following code snippet,

```
@Local
public interface LocalEjb {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
   public String getIt();
}

@Stateless
@Path("/stateless")
public class StatelessEjbResource implements LocalEjb {
    @Override
    public String getIt() {
        return "Hi Stateless!";
    }
}
```

I have a doubt whether the Ejb class's getIt() method will actually reflect the @GET annotation since the @GET annotation is NOT defined with @Inherited meta-annotation.

Can someone please elaborate and clarify?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer Chapter 3, Section 3.6 - Annotation Inheritance, in the JSR339 specification document.

[JSR339 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html)

> jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf